# Splitting Variables with multiple arguments?

Tags: java, string, variables, parameters

```
String[] textA = a.split("\\s"); //splits the string when it meets a white space character
```

I want to make it so when it meets either a , or a . it would still split. Is there any way I can achieve this with multiple conditions without doing an if statement?

For example `a.split("\\s || ,");` something like this.

Comment: maybe you're trying to do `a.split("\\s|,|\\.");` ?

Comment: You can use string tokenizer as well

Comment: you can use a class of characters `a.split("[\\s,\\.]+");`

Comment: @YCF_L Thanks, your suggestion worked, also can you tell me what that + at the end does? Thanks again!

Comment: Its mean one or more time, consider for example you have one or more spaces in your string

Comment: @OP, you may find that https://regex101.com/ is helpful in decoding regular expressions. Unfortunately, they don't implement Java-flavour ones, but that's relatively trivial insofar as you just escape the necessary characters as needed